# Iterate (/) a multivalent function

Tags: kdb

How do you iterate a function of multivalent rank (>1), e.g. `f:{[x;y] ...}` where the function inputs in the next iteration step depend on the last iteration step? Examples in [the reference manual](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#converge-iterate) only iterate unary functions.

I was able to achieve this indirectly (and verbosely) by passing a dictionary of arguments (state) into unary function:

```
f:{[arg] key[arg]!(min arg;arg[`y]-2)}                                                          
f/[{0<x`x};`x`y!6 3]
```

Note that projection, e.g. `f[x;]/[whilecond;y]` would only work in the scenario where the `x` in the next iteration step does ***not*** depend on the result of the last iteration (i.e. when x is path-independent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relation to Rahul's answer, you could use one of the following (slightly less verbose) methods to achieve the same result:

```
q)g:{(min x,y;y-2)}
q)(g .)/[{0<x 0};6 3]
-1 -3
q).[g]/[{0<x 0};6 3]
-1 -3
```

Alternatively, you could use the .z.s self function, which recursively calls the function g and takes the output of the last iteration as its arguments. For example,

```
q)g:{[x;y] x: min x,y; y:y-2; $[x<0; (x;y); .z.s[x;y]]}
q)g[6;3]
-1 -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Function that is used with '/' and '\' can only accept result from last iteration as a single item which means only 1 function parameter is reserved for the result. It is unary in that sense.

For function whose multiple input parameters depends on last iteration result, one solution is to wrap that function inside a unary function and use apply operator to execute that function on the last iteration result.

Ex:

```
      q) g:{(min x,y;y-2)}  / function with rank 2
      q) f:{x . y}[g;]   / function g wrapped inside unary function to iterate
      q) f/[{0<x 0};6 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Over time I stumbled upon even shorter way which does not require parentheses or brackets:

```
q)g:{(min x,y;y-2)}
q){0<x 0} g//6 3
-1 -3
```

Why does double `over` (`//`) work ? The `/` adverb can sometimes be used in place of the `.` (`apply`) operator:

```
q)(*) . 2 3
6
q)(*/) 2 3
6
```